# Printing text on card printer

Tags: .net, printing

I'm working on a card printer, where some text will be printed on front page.  The printer sdk lacks code samples for this kind of operation. Therefore, i'm asking if somebody has (dotnet) code examples, on how to write/draw text string on the card.

the printer is a evolis primacy.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Evolis Premium SDK here: https://www.evolis.com/drivers-support/drivers-evolis-sdk-card-printer

The Premium SDK serves developers willing to communicate with one or many Evolis printers from their own software environment, while leveraging the Evolis Premium Suite key features.

**Several resources are made available:**

- **A quick start guide** (first step)
- A clear and short **programming reference guide**
- A print settings guide (PrintSettingsGuide.pdf)
- **Code samples** for common programming languages (C#, C++, Python, VB.Net et Java), for:
- Connecting to the ESPF (Evolis Service Provider Framework) server
- Sending a request (encode, print in single or dual-sided mode, in color or monochrome...)
- Reading and interpreting the server’s response
- **A set of requests** (in .txt format) for the most common use cases
- A command line tool, for testing requests to be sent (ESPF request tool)
- **A demo program in C#** for getting started with the Premium SDK, through sending simple request using existing code samples.
- A FAQ (Frequently Asked Questions)

**Technical requirements**

- List item
- Development languages:

  - any type of language supporting TCP/IP socket communication (C, C#, C++, VB.Net, Java, Delphi, PHP, Python…)
- Operating systems:

  - Evolis Premium Suite host computer: Windows® XP SP3, Vista, 7, 8 & 10
  - Premium SDK clients: any operating system (Windows®, Mac, Linux, iOS, Android…)

Source: https://www.evolis.com/evolis-premium-sdk-software-development-kit#tab-0-2

Comment: link doesn't worked